# Reduce code duplication when reading different types of numbers from console

Tags: java, console, java.util.scanner

I have created three methods readLong, readInt and readDouble that basically does the same thing. Only difference is the method called by a scanner. How can I reduce duplicate code by turning them all to one method?

```
public long readLong(String description)
    {
        System.out.println(description);
        long nrToReturn = 0;
        boolean acceptedValue = false;

        do {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Choose one: ");
            try
            {
                nrToReturn = consoleScanner.nextLong(); //Only line thats different except return value
                acceptedValue = true;
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                acceptedValue = false;
                consoleScanner.nextLine();
            }
        }while (!acceptedValue);

        consoleScanner.nextLine();
        return nrToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Post this question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Take a look at generic types in Java

Comment: How does the caller of these methods know which one to invoke?

Comment: I think the caller knows which one to invoke but the problem is to make a one method public static <T extends Number> T readNumber(String description)

Comment: @Michu93 I tried that but the problem is that the generic type T does not accept a Long. The compiler syes "Cannot cast long to T".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go with one idea:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    private Scanner consoleScanner;

    public ScannerTest() {
        consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
    private <T extends Number> T readType(String description, Class<T> desiredType) {
        System.out.println(description);
        Number result = null;

        while (result == null) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Choose one: ");
            try {
                if (Integer.class.equals(desiredType)) {
                    result = new Integer(consoleScanner.nextInt());
                } else if (Long.class.equals(desiredType)) {
                    result = new Long(consoleScanner.nextLong());
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                consoleScanner.nextLine();
            }
        }

        consoleScanner.nextLine();
        return (T) result;
    }

    public long readLong(String description) {
        return this.readType(description, Long.class);
    }

    public int readInt(String description) {
        return this.readType(description, Integer.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScannerTest t = new ScannerTest();
        t.readLong("Reading a long value...");
        t.readInt("Reading an integer value...");
    }  
}
```

**Update**, following @Michu93 idea of a single transparent method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    private Scanner consoleScanner;

    public ScannerTest() {
        consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Number> T readNumber(String description) {
        System.out.println(description);
        Number result = null;

        while (result == null) {
            System.out.print("\nChoose one: ");
            String textRead = consoleScanner.next();

            try {
                result = new Integer(textRead);
            } catch(Exception e1) {
                try {
                    result = new Long(textRead);
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    try {
                        result = new Double(textRead);
                    } catch (Exception e3) {
                    }
                }
            }
            consoleScanner.nextLine();
        }

        return (T) result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScannerTest t = new ScannerTest();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Number input = t.readNumber(i + ": Reading int, long or double...");
            System.out.println("Input class: " + input.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            System.out.println("Input value: " + input);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Edit: I was thinking the same about using generics instead of Object, as  @Michu93 pointed out. But I don't think it is possible to make such a public method [public static <T extends Number> T readNumber(String description)]  without informing which type of input is needed, unless you define an hierarchy between types and try reading each type untill success each time method is called. Updated my answer to fit the <T extends Number> idea. [cannot comment on original thread as I'm not 50 pts yet, sorry].